# Bending arrow between 2 nodes adds additional arrow when using anchors

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

I want to do a bending arrow between two nodes of a TikZ picture, and using the border anchors (`north`, `east`, `south`...). Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (n1) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw] (n2) at (1,0) {};
\draw[->] (n1.east) edge[bend left] (n2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image: output]

But I want:

[image]

If I remove the bending (i.e. `(n1.east) -- (n2.west)`), or if I remove the anchor of the starting node (i.e. `(n1) -- (n2.west)`), or when I do a simple line and not an arrow (i.e. `\draw[]`) there is no unexpected behaviour, but when I have all of this at once, the additional arrow appears.

I want a solution that keeps the anchors, the arrow and the bending.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Instead of `edge` use `to` ...

Comment: Or `\path` instead of `\draw` with edges.